# "Class 'XMLWriter' not found" Error in php | php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm is missing

Tags: php, xml, package, centos6, php-5.5

I am getting this error in `PHP` in server `Fatal Error (E_ERROR): Class 'XMLWriter' not found` . we are using `Cent OS 6`

After exploring some sites, we found that we need to install [php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/3/srodzaj/1/search/php-dom(x86-64)). But the link is not working, I am not able to get this package. we are using `PHP 5.5.24`. We can not upgrade our PHP because of dependency with other products.Can we resolve this error without upgrading the `PHP`. Thanks !!!

**UPDATE:** we are using https://rollbar.com/ for error handing.

Comment: Did you tried `yum install php-xml`?

Comment: not tried but to install particular class we need that package

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure to understand. What does it display if you try `yum install php-xml` from command line?

Comment: It says that 
`php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64` is obsoleted. But we can not update the PHP version due to dependency with other codes

Comment: <<<<Loaded plugins: replace, security
Setting up Install Process
Package php55w-xml is obsoleted by php-xml, trying to install php-xml-5.6.29-0.1.RC1.el6.remi.x86_64 instead
Resolving Dependencies >>>>>This is what I get

Comment: I just need this package `php55w-xml-5.5.24-1.w6.x86_64.rpm` but can not find it in any archive. If possible, please share url for this package.

Answer (score 3):

Install php7-xmlwriter

yum install php-7xmlwriter

Comment: first command works for me. thanks

Answer (score 1):

on Centos 7, in my case this works:

```
yum install php-xml
service httpd restart
```